# Why is AWS Lambda returning a Key Error when trying to upload an image to S3 and updating a DynamoDB Table with API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to upload a binary Image to S3 and update a DynamoDB table in the same AWS Lambda Function. The problem is, whenever I try to make an API call, I get the following error in postman:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "'itemId'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "requestId": "bccaead6-cb60-4a5e-9fc7-14ff25380451",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=event[\"itemId\"] + \".png\", Body=decode_content)\n"
    ]
}
```

My events section takes in 3 Strings and whenever I try and access those strings, I get this error. However, if I try and access them without trying to upload to an S3 Bucket, everything works fine. My Lambda Function looks like this:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64

dynamoclient = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
table = dynamoclient.Table("Items")

bucket = "images"
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    get_file_content = event["content"]
    decode_content = base64.b64decode(get_file_content)
    
    s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=event["itemId"] + ".png", Body=decode_content)
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'itemID': event["itemId"],
            'itemName': event['itemName'],
            'itemDescription': event['itemDescription']
        }
    )
    return {
        "code":200, 
        "message": "Item was added successfully"
    }
```

Again, if I remove everything about the S3 file upload, everything works fine and I am able to update the DynamoDB table successfully. As for the API Gateway side, I have added the `image/png` to the Binary Media Types section. Additionally, for the Mapping Templates section for AWS API Gateway, I have added the content type `image/png`. In the template for the content type, I have the following lines:

```
{
    "content": "$input.body"
}
```

For my Postman POST request, in the headers section, I have put this:
[image: Postman Headers Section]

Finally, for the body section, I have added the raw event data with this:

```
{
  "itemId": "0fx170",
  "itemName": "Mouse",
  "itemDescription": "Smooth"
}
```

Lastly, for the binary section, I have uploaded my PNG file.
What could be going wrong?

Comment: What is the actual `event`? Can your `print(event)` and check?

Comment: It seems to be ```{'itemId': '0fx133', 'itemName': 'Bannana', 'itemDescription': 'Test number 2'}``` This is only when I do it from the console Test Event with just the 3 strings and no files. When I actually attach a file, it shows the first error message.

Comment: When running with a lambda, the [query string parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html) will be under a value like `event['queryStringParameters']['itemId']`.

Comment: But I am not using queryStringParameters. When I tried it like that it did not work. What I had to do was add the itemID, itemName, and itemDescription in the raw data section of postman. It worked fine until I added the S3 stuff.

Comment: Sadly your event nor your code match. its not possible to obtain your error. You would first error out here `event["content"]` as your event does not contain `content`.

Comment: That is when I use Lambda's test event without a file. When I do add the content in postman, I get the first error above. Note that ```content``` is a file. That is why in AWS API Gateway, I have to add

`{"content": "$input.body"}`

Comment: enable debug logs on api gateway, it will show in cloudwatch exactly what came into api gateway, how it was processed on integration & response parts. It will be much easier to see what's happening. If it's not in API gateway, make sure s3 adding meta data of content type, and image is <6mb (lambda payload limit). also i highly recommend to consider using signed upload urls of s3 for data upload. you are burning lambda time when piping bits through it.

Comment: Thank you Lukas. I was wondering though, is using Lambda to upload a file with API Gateway over engineering? Would it be better to just upload it using API Gateway without the Lambda Function?